# Ruby on rails date checking..help please

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

@a = a Date
@b = Todays date
In my project I want to confirm @b is not more than 1 day from @a.
means when a user registered at @a he want to activate his account within 1 day.How can we do that..Am using Ruby on rails 2.3.8

NB: Ask me if u didn't get my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def not_long_ago?( date )
  ((DateTime.now - 1.day)..DateTime.now) === date
end
```

or just

```
def not_long_ago?( date )
  date >= DateTime.now - 1.day
end
```

and the best one (rails way, I think)

```
def not_long_ago?( date )
  date >= 1.day.ago
end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (date_in_question < 1.day.ago)
  # allow signup
else
  # don't allow signup
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function to check if a date is within a day of today's date:

```
def within_a_day? date
  Date.today-1.day <= date && date <= Date.today+1.day
end
```

Comment: Wow...too fast.Thanks a lot for your quick reply.

Comment: Just realized you wanted +/- a whole day, so I added <= instead of <, since < will only match the current date.

Comment: @Pan-thomakos k thanks again.. From where i can study these kind of ruby operators.. actually i don't know about these kind of operators( <= , <=> etc)

Comment: Oh.. sorry is that less than or equal to...K and what about this one <=> ?

Comment: Actually you should use `DateTime` class here. So there is no need to check if `date <= Date.today + 1.day` because it looks like a future :)

Comment: The <=> operator is a general comparison operator that return 0, -1, 1 for equal, less than or greater than. It can be used with the Comparable module to determine how two objects compare.

Comment: @fl00r the reason I used Date was because that was referenced in the original post.